# Changes in Gambio shopsystem are not effective on live server

Tags: html, caching, e-commerce, gambio

I had to make some changes on a Gambio shopsystem.
All changes I made were tested on a local server first and then pushed to the live server.

The problem now is, that most of the changes are applied correctly but one file really does not.

The one that does not work is in the path `./templates/shopname/module/product_listing/product_listing_v1.html`

I only changed one html-tag in there.

---

Now to the things I have tried.

1. I uploaded it several times, so there is no chance at all, that it is not really there.
2. I cleared the folder `./cache/`
3. I cleared the folder `./templates_c`
4. I disabled the cache for the whole system
5. I made sure there is no fallback, so it is really only one file that should work

On the local server the changes I made worked immediately. On the live server, it did not work and the original html-tag is still there on the live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some files in Gambio the software takes template files out of one table. In the backend of the shop it is possible to select the specific file from the folder

If there is more than one file which can be selected and there is no selected file, the system automaticly takes the last one by default.

There are 2 ways to solve the problem:

1. Delete all other possible duplicate files, like copys or other unused files.
   *This is the one I recommend.*
2. You can select the template file you need for every product or category. *That can be a real pain.*